# historyjs / HTML5 pushState "data" argument not saving properties of object that are functions

Tags: jquery, pushstate, history.js

I'm attempting to use pushState in my web application like so:

```
//default settings
    var ds = {
        path: window.module.Globals.prototype.base_url, //location misc variable for my app
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {},
        target: 'main_swap_area',
        pre_ajax_callback: function(scope){ console.log('pac'); },
        post_success_callback: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR, scope){ console.log('psc'); },
        scope: this
    };

    History.pushState(ds, 'Title 1', ds.path);
```

And I have a callback function listening for the '`statechange`' event

```
jQuery(window).bind('statechange',function(){


        var
            State = History.getState(),
            url = State.url;

        console.log(State); // State.data is object with all original properties EXCEPT properties that contained functions as values


    }); // end onStateChange
```

The output of my console is an object with all my original properties/values, except all the properties that had functions for values. Why are these being dropped/not returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At one point many `pushState` implementations used JSON to serialize and deserialize objects. Newer browser versions use something called [the structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/The_structured_clone_algorithm).

In both cases, `Error` and `Function` objects are not supported, so you can't use them as part of your `pushState` state. Trying to do this typically results in a DATA_CLONE_ERR exception, but perhaps the error event is not bubbling up.

If you really want to store a function, I see that the structured clone algorithm supports `Blob` cloning so it's possible you can load your function as a `<script>` node, with possible storing of this text blob as a `Blob` in local store. You'd have to `eval` it to use it (which can be dangerous if used incorrectly), but I could see something like this working even if not completely elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought by Why not pass the function name through the json, if it exists in the data create a new function then exec it

```
temp = new Function(State.data.pre_ajax_callback);
temp();
```